# Plugin class doesn't exist

Tags: magento2

I have created a very simple plugin but at the time of compile code (run bin/magento setup:di:compile command)  it show Plugin class doesn't exist.  Below is my module code

Module structure:

Webkeon\DynamicProduct

registration.php code

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Webkeon_DynamicProduct',
    __DIR__
);
```

Webkeon\DynamicProduct\etc

module.xml  code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Webkeon_DynamicProduct" setup_version="0.0.2">
</module>
</config>
```

di.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item">
    <plugin name="Wekeon_DynamicProduct_Plugin_Magento_Quote_Model_Quote_Item" 
              type="Wekeon\DynamicProduct\Plugin\ItemPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
</type>

</config>
```

Webkeon\DynamicProduct\Plugin

ItemPlugin.php code

```
<?php
namespace Webkeon\DynamicProduct\Plugin;

class ItemPlugin
{
    
    public function afterSetProduct(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $subject,$result){
        
        
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/productplugin.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        
        $logger->debug('product name plugin <br>');
        
        $subject->setName('New Name');
    }

}
```

Any one let me know where i am doing wrong it is very simple plugin that are overwriting public function.

Thanks

Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

Plugin name does not match module name.

```
<plugin name="Wekeon_DynamicProduct_Plugin_Magento_Quote_Model_Quote_Item" 
          type="Wekeon\DynamicProduct\Plugin\ItemPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
```

and module is Webkeon\DynamicProduct

Add the letter B

```
<plugin name="Webkeon_DynamicProduct_Plugin_Magento_Quote_Model_Quote_Item" 
          type="Webkeon\DynamicProduct\Plugin\ItemPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
```